# why does friend declaration on a lambda does not work on gcc

Tags: c++, lambda

See this simple example,

```
constexpr auto f = [](const auto& foo){
    foo.fun2();
};

struct Foo{
    friend decltype(f);

    void fun1() const{
        f(*this);
    }

    private:
    void fun2() const{}
};

int main(){
    Foo foo{};
    foo.fun1();
}
```

the friend declaration does not seem to work. gcc complains that the `fun2` is private even though `f` is given the access.

this results in compiler error

```
<source>: In instantiation of '<lambda(const auto:1&)> [with auto:1 = Foo]':

<source>:9:16:   required from here

<source>:2:13: error: 'void Foo::fun2() const' is private within this context

    2 |     foo.fun2();

      |     ~~~~~~~~^~

<source>:13:10: note: declared private here

   13 |     void fun2() const{}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yv8rxf)

Comment: Is that supposed to work? If it does, neat.

Comment: Looks like a bug. [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/1h4jK5) is fine with it.

Comment: MSVC also doesn't complain.

Comment: This lambda is not really a lambda, but a template. This is what likely confuses gcc.

Comment: GCC bug reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102791